# What's the best approach to do JSHint checks in Teamcity

Tags: teamcity, jshint

I couldn't find any easy solution for JSHinting Javascript code in Teamcity.
As far as I can tell I'll need to install node.js on the build agent to be able to run JSHint from the command prompt.
Is there a solution that doesn't involve installing a new platform on the build server? Maybe a simple executable copied to a network share?

We use windows machines and Visual Studio for the development.